# PHP foreach nested loop not accepting portion of array

Tags: php, arrays

When I try to extract the user id from my array I get the error:

> [31-May-2016 21:10:00 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument
>   supplied for foreach() in filename.php line 24

Here is the code:

```
$users = $lists->users;
foreach($users as $user) 
{
    $true_id = $user->id;
    foreach ($true_id as $i => $id) 
    {
        if (empty($friends->ids) or !in_array($id, $friends->ids)) 
        {
            $ret = $toa->post('friendships/create', array('user_id' => $id));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to assign the objects as arrays.

```
$users = (array) $lists->users;
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $true_id = (array) $user->id;
    foreach ($true_id as $i => $id) {
        if (empty($friends->ids) || in_array($id, $friends->ids) === false) {
            $ret = $toa->post('friendships/create', array('user_id' => $id));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it works, since a cast will make a scalar to a single field of an array, however, it does not make sense and is unnecessary overhead. Try `$id = 1;
$arr = (array) $id;
var_dump($arr);` It will give you `array(1)`. You don't need to iterate, when you have a `scalar $id`. IDs are not expected to be anything other than an integer or a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate on `$user->id`, however, this does not seem to be an iterable object.

Just access the scalar field `id` without any nested loop:

```
$users = (array) $lists->users;
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if (empty($friends->ids) || in_array($user->id, $friends->ids) === false) {
        $ret = $toa->post('friendships/create', array('user_id' => $user->id));
    }
}
```